# Where I could find the api reference for angularjs typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I come from work with Angularjs 1.4 and pure javascript and now I started to work with Angularjs 1.5 but now with Typescript, and I couldn't find docs to my help.
For example I have to guess the name of the services like `$q` or `$timeout` to inject to my classes. That would be `angular.IQService` and `angular.ITimeoutService` respectively.

I hope to be clear. Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DefinitelyTyped repository contains [readme file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/angular#services-and-other-injectables) together with respective AngularJS definitions,

> All known services interfaces have been defined, and were named using
>   the following convention:
>
> I + 'ServiceName' + 'Service'
>
> So, for instance, the $parse service has it's interface defined as
>   ng.IParseService.
>
> Service providers, by the same logic, follow this convention:
>
> I + 'ServiceName' + 'Provider'
>
> The $httpProvider, thus, is defined by ng.IHttpProvider.

The most straightforward way to figure out typings is to look into source file, either local `@types` package or [DefinitelyTyped repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts). TypeScript works best with IDE, where typings can be inspected and auto-completed without any documentation.

Additionally, auto-generated documentation from AngularJS typings is available [here](http://ng-table.com/api-docs/modules/angular.html).

Answer (score 0):

> For example I have to guess the name of the services like $q or $timeout to inject to my classes. That would be angular.IQService and angular.ITimeoutService respectively.

Follows the convention `I<NameOfService>Service`. e.g. `$interval` would be `IIntervalService`